# Flexbox grow container that grows to a certain height but then scrolls

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

If I have a fixed height div containing 2 vertical divs, I want to have the first div be the height of the content, up to 80% of the parent div, at which point it will have its content scroll for the rest of it. The second div should grow for the rest of the parent container, down to a minimum height.

I've tried a lot of variations to get it to do what I want but I can't figure out how to do it without Javascript.

I made an example [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GxYaQR) for people to look at and modify. I know I could do it in JS but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without.

```
<body layout="row" ng-app="myApp" ng-cloak>

  <div flex layout="column" class="boxWithHeight" layout-padding>
    <section flex="grow" style="overflow-y:auto"><div>Enter in lots of content here</div></section>
    <section style="min-height:100px">flex</section>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <script>angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.

**Demo with overflow**

```css
.wrap {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  background: lightblue;
  max-height: 80%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.spacer {
  height: 200px; /* for demo purposes */
}

footer {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, pariatur cumque? Accusantium eius hic laboriosam, odio amet repellendus quo perferendis unde iure quasi, eaque similique eos architecto illo voluptatibus voluptate doloribus atque
      in deleniti placeat corrupti saepe. Animi, quisquam officia?</p>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

**Demo with no overflow**

```css
.wrap {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5vh auto;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  background: lightblue;
  max-height: 80%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.spacer {}

footer {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, pariatur cumque? Accusantium eius hic laboriosam, odio amet repellendus quo perferendis unde iure quasi, eaque similique eos architecto illo voluptatibus voluptate doloribus atque
      in deleniti placeat corrupti saepe. Animi, quisquam officia?</p>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, beautiful. You made it look so simple.